# How to read the x,y,z coordinates of point cloud from the LIDAR SICK LMS 200

Tags: ros, pcl, sicklms

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Goal:** To employ obstacle avoidance by interpreting the data from the LIDAR using PCL

**Description:**
Hi everyone,
I am working with a LIDAR device for the first time. I used the sick toolbox ros wrapper for reading the values from the LIDAR. I converted the "scan" topic given out by the LIDAR device to point-cloud 2 format.
here is the program:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h>
  
 ros::Publisher pub;
 
class My_Filter {
     public:
        My_Filter();
        void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan);
     private:
        ros::NodeHandle node_;
        laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;
        tf::TransformListener tfListener_;

        ros::Publisher point_cloud_publisher_;
        ros::Subscriber scan_sub_;
         };

My_Filter::My_Filter(){
        scan_sub_ = node_.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> ("/scan", 100, &My_Filter::scanCallback, this);
        point_cloud_publisher_ = node_.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/cloud", 100, false);
        tfListener_.setExtrapolationLimit(ros::Duration(0.1));
}

void My_Filter::scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan){
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
    
    projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("/laser", *scan, cloud, tfListener_);
    point_cloud_publisher_.publish(cloud);
}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_filter");

    My_Filter filter;

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

This above node gives out the point cloud 2 topic "cloud". I subscribed to this topic in the following program. I was successful in reading the widht and height of the point clouds,but I need some help reading the X,Y,Z coordinates. I also need to know how to access the other objects which might be useful in data processing.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h>
#include <pcl/ros/conversions.h> 
ros::Publisher pub;
void cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
  // ... do data processing
 printf ("Cloud: width = %d, height = %d\n", input->width,input->height);
  
  BOOST_FOREACH (const pcl::PointXYZ& pt, input->points)
  printf ("\t(%f, %f, %f)\n", pt.x, pt.y, pt.z);
  // Publish the data
 // pub.publish (output);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Initialize ROS
  ros::init (argc, argv, "pcs200");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  // Create a ROS subscriber for the input point cloud
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("/cloud", 100, cloud_cb);

  // Create a ROS publisher for the output point cloud
  pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("output", 100,false);

  // Spin
  ros::spin ();
}
```

Here is the output for that:

```
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  Scanning dependencies of target pcs200
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcs200.dir/src/pcs200.o
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp: In function ‘void cloud_cb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr&)’:
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  /home/karthik/ros_workspace/pcs200/src/pcs200.cpp:17: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcs200.dir/src/pcs200.o] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcs200.dir/all] Error 2
```

Above is the error message generated. I know I  am missing something very simple here. I am open to alternative suggestions also. The goal is to employ obstacle avoidance using PCL. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41306/how-to-read-the-x,y,z-coordinates-of-point-cloud-from-the-lidar-sick-lms-200./) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Metal!

The error message

```
`const struct sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘points’
```

is telling the truth, the variable *input* has type sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 and has no member called points, you can see its definition [here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html).

You can use *input->data* or transform *input* to a pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ which is somewhat easier to use.

You can do it like this

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> input_;
pcl::fromROSMsg(*input, input_);
```

I hope this is helpful for you.
Martin.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on 2012-08-15**:
It did rectify the error,thank you. But the z is always showing as zero. Also could you please recommend the approach to implement obstacle avoidance using sick lidar?. Is PCL a good approach ?

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-08-15**:
I might be mistaken, I have never worked with LIDAR, but as far as I know the readings of a LIDAR sensor are in 2D, usually in the plane X,Y, unless you are artificially tilting it with a motor. So to me it makes sense that the Z is always zero.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-08-15**:
As for the best approach to implement obstacle avoidance using sick lidar, I would start a new question, so people with more experience than me can guide you. Also, you should check out the navigation stack http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/ lots of stuff already implemented there

**Comment by [Ajay Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/12121/ajay-jain/) on 2015-02-09**:
Is there a way to use fromROSMsg in pcl_conversions or pcl_ros with Python? I have a Python node that subscribes to LaserScan data, converts the LaserScan to a PointCloud2 message, and need to extract the x,y data from this point cloud.

**Comment by [Ajay Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/12121/ajay-jain/) on 2015-02-09**:
I made a separate question: http://answers.ros.org/question/202787/using-pointcloud2-data-getting-xy-points-in-python/

**Comment by [Tooght](https://answers.ros.org/users/28665/tooght/) on 2016-12-02**:
What are the CmakeLists.txt and package codes for this project?

**Comment by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) on 2017-04-20**:
https://pastebin.com/i71RQcU2 this is my full code,,

please have a look

the image view is crashing but i am getting values though,, also,, there is nothing in x y and z !!